# "The requested resource is not available" when deploying Jersey application in Tomcat

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to build a simple Restful api which returns user details.

I have refered [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm) link.

Following are my classes:

**API Service class:**

```
package com.demoapp;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.omg.Messaging.SyncScopeHelper;


@Path("/AddUserApi") 
public class AddUserApi {

     @GET 
       @Path("/users") 
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
       public List<User> getUsers(){ 
          return UserUtil.getUserList(); 
       }  
}
```

**Dao Class:**

```
package com.demoapp;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement(name = "user") 
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String name="";
    String u_name="";
    String password="";
    String email="";
    String user_type="";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getU_name() {
        return u_name;
    }
    public void setU_name(String u_name) {
        this.u_name = u_name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getUser_type() {
        return user_type;
    }
    public void setUser_type(String user_type) {
        this.user_type = user_type;
    }

}
```

**Utils class:**

```
package com.demoapp;

import java.util.List;

public class UserUtil {

    public static String mysql_ip="jdbc:mysql://10.119.32.86/";
    public static String metadata_database="haas";
    public static String mysql_username="root";
    public static String mysql_password="";

    public static List<User> getUserList(){
        List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();

        User user=new User();
        user.setName("abc");
        user.setU_name("ab_c");
        user.setPassword("1234");
        user.setUser_type("normal");
        user.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");

        users.add(user);

        return users;
     }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>UserAPI</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>com.demoapp</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

I have downloaded the jersey jar from the site and extracted 3 folders and added those jars in build path.

I have done everything according to the tutorial.
Still its showing this error:

[image: error]
Could you please suggest a way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Provided the server is up and running and the application is deployed without errors, your endpoint should be available in the following URL:

```
http://[host]:[port]/[context]/rest/AddUserApi/users
```

Where:

- `[context]` is the name of your WAR file (without the `.war` extension).
- `/rest` comes from the `web.xml`: `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>`.
- `/AddUserApi` comes from the `@Path` annotation on the `AddUserApi` class.
- `/users` comes from `@Path` annotation on the `getUsers()` method.

Comment: i am running the project on server by clicking on run as server....so do you mean i have to make war and deploy it on a server and then use the link?

Comment: @satishsilveri No, you don't need to manually create a WAR file because your IDE is doing it for you (actually, it's very likely that your application is being deployed as an exploded WAR folder, but it doesn't matter). For a dynamic web project, most IDEs use the project name as `[context]` by default.

Comment: Mazzochi Molin so i done that only running from IDE and i am assuming it should create this link localhost:8082/UserAPI/rest/AddUserApi/users automatically...correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @satishsilveri I don't know what you mean with _create this link ... automatically_. But if the server is running on the `8082` port and the application is deployed without errors on the `UserAPI` context, you should be able to perform a `GET` request to `http://localhost:8082/UserAPI/rest/AddUserApi/users` and get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be: localhost:8082/UserAPI/rest/AddUserApi/users

Comment: Where did you get the port `8082` and the context `UserAPI`?

Comment: Are you sure the opened port is 8082 instead of 8080?